# Select date where there is data in-between

Tags: mysql

I have todayRainSoFar column which is filled into db every minute, and i would like to find out the maximum duration of rain this month, ie when it started to rain and how long did it last.

for example it started to rain 2014-04-01 at 08:00 and it was raining without pause until 2014-04-05 10:00

i have trouble with combined queries.

```
// this will select rows when there was any rain this month
SELECT LogDateTime, TodayRainSoFar 
FROM sibeniku_monthly 
WHERE TodayRainSoFar > 0.0
AND DATE_FORMAT(LogDateTime, "%m.") = 04
```

now I am looking for something to count maximum duration of in-between rows (LogDateTime is datetime and range is 1 minute), smth like

```
AND MAX (COUNT BETWEEN rows)
```

Comment: Pls share sample data & desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The approach used below is to keep a counter of consecutive minutes of rain and then get the row which has maximum value of the counter (this would give you the maximum duration of consecutive rain). Counter will be reset to 0 if rain has ended.

```
SELECT DATE_SUB(LogDateTime, INTERVAL counter MINUTE) AS StartTime, LogDateTime AS EndTime FROM (
  SELECT IF(TodayRainSoFar = 0, @i:=0, @i:=@i+1) AS `counter`, 
    LogDateTime, TodayRainSoFar
  FROM
    sibeniku_monthly, (SELECT @i:= 0) i
  ORDER BY LogDateTime
) t
ORDER BY `counter` DESC
LIMIT 0,1
```

**Working Demo**: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8578b8/8

Comment: ty =) i will study this example since I never used IF in mysql statements so far

Comment: @Marko to explore this query, try running the inner query first and see the results.

Answer (score -1):

Try using DATEDIFF in your script, here is a link: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx

This will give you everything you need to know about DATEDIFF.